# Computing Feigenbaum Constant in Java

Tags: chaos-theory

Is there a way to code a Java program that computes the Feigenbaum constant (which is around 4.66) for the function $F(x) = r\cdot\sin(\pi\cdot x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Here [Keith Briggs - PhD thesis (University of Melbourne 1997) Feigenbaum scaling in discrete dynamical systems](http://keithbriggs.info/thesis.html)  you can find description of algorithm